# could not get next sequence value in DB2 10.5 when testing DAO class with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, db2

I have installed new database with sequences in my local and able to see the next sequence values through the command prompt. But when I am trying to test the DAO classes using JUnit I am getting the following errors. 
The below error states that don't have privilige...but I can able to get the next sequence values using cmnd prompt.

ERROR:

Hibernate: values nextval for SEQUENCE_ID
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -551, SQLState: 42501
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=user;USAGE;SEQUENCE_ID, DRIVER=3.66.46
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-551;42501;user;USAGE;SEQUENCE_ID, DRIVER=3.66.46
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
12-Dec-2014 19:16:52 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-551;42501;user;USAGE;SEQUENCE_ID, DRIVER=3.66.46
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator$1.getNextValue(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.OptimizerFactory$LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(OptimizerFactory.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy14.createNewService(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=user;USAGE;SEQUENCE_ID, DRIVER=3.66.46
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:741)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2763)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.d(oo.java:2751)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.a(oo.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.a(po.java:7379)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.h(ab.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.o.a(o.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.tb.i(tb.java:145)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.ib(oo.java:2169)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.tc(po.java:3547)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4345)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.gc(po.java:739)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.executeQuery(po.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:112)
    ... 53 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLSTATE 42501  The authorization ID does not have the privilege to perform the specified operation on the identified object.

You just need to give the database user account the necessary permissions.

Comment: I have created the DB and I am able to get the sequence values when i try from command prompt. I f I dont have the priviliges then even in command prompt it should through same error, but it's not

Comment: Are you sure hibernate is connecting with the same database user account?

Comment: Yes, hibernarte is connecting to the same database using the same user.